# Missing transaction in getSignaturesForAddress

Tags: getsignaturesforaddress

Calling either public or private RPC nodes with:

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"id": 1,
"method": "getSignaturesForAddress",
"params": [
    "CTXyXJmT81XvfNB2DWmuthXyshCnyN5JXfCCGjWTTfKC",
    {
        "commitment": "finalized",
        "until": "3huxUKinafZSCpShSrSsSRUffwqqXVWuyoTYg2rzdXDAQ4rr9TYeDC6LRD8U6w7Y3QSJzzdq8Ago6jwFH4EfHoyc"
    }
]
}
```

Yields only 1 transaction:

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"result": [
    {
        "blockTime": 1664889915,
        "confirmationStatus": "finalized",
        "err": null,
        "memo": null,
        "signature": "5RuXYfENRrWXizWHaZwGLzv83XAUByvgaev7e2mh2TKBeVBdNaEVQpgHohZ6G5nGXJoG1gGaB9emkdRH2dDd5GA2",
        "slot": 153650044
    }
],
"id": 1
}
```

Yet https://solscan.io/token/CTXyXJmT81XvfNB2DWmuthXyshCnyN5JXfCCGjWTTfKC clearly shows a FINALIZED transaction from 12h ago that is missing: 57VSjvwCUDGgn5XbuAucHRqm2h9XVuiYrvYJgo7UfWXM82MkATQUvj2kakoFf3QcpvAuWC8VaWELpwnDcNFi9WfC. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Account in the query isn’t in the account list of tx 57VSjv…
CTXyXJmT81XvfNB2DWmuthXyshCnyN5JXfCCGjWTTfKC

The Solanart Sell contract transfers the Current Token Account
6fJXosismWFuYQ6gkiNwugd1TpLAGjFRy3v7V3MUu5db

When the buy happens, it’s the "6fJXos.." account that’s transferred, not the CTXyXJ…

Sell
https://solscan.io/tx/5RuXYfENRrWXizWHaZwGLzv83XAUByvgaev7e2mh2TKBeVBdNaEVQpgHohZ6G5nGXJoG1gGaB9emkdRH2dDd5GA2
buy
https://solscan.io/tx/57VSjvwCUDGgn5XbuAucHRqm2h9XVuiYrvYJgo7UfWXM82MkATQUvj2kakoFf3QcpvAuWC8VaWELpwnDcNFi9WfC

getSignaturesForAddress is insufficient for monitoring txs related to transfers/sales when the destination pubkey isn't in the tx, because it's the token account address in those txs.

Systems that are tracking NFT sales and other NFT-related events are typically parsing blocks and getting follow-up information about account ownership via the RPC itself to figure out who owns the token accounts in question. could do this via subscription too.

You may be interested in something like webhooks on https://helius.xyz/ so you can get event payloads when NFT transfers happen.

There are other ways like tracking the latest token account address of each token and then updating which one to track after each transfer.

Answer (score 1):

I had a bad assumption that a token transfer will always include the token itself in a transaction's accounts list. Now I know!